# What is the meaning of if ! [[ -S $variable ]]?

Tags: bash

I know... a petty fundamental question but I can't find what the "-S" is testing for?

```
BORG_SOCKET="${BORG_SOCKET:-/run/borg.sock}"
if ! [[ -S $BORG_SOCKET ]]; then
  echo "err: borg socket does not exist" >&2
  exit 10
...
```

Comment: See: `help test | grep -- -S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`-S` tests whether the given path exists and is a socket](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) (the link documents `test`, but the `[[` `-S` operator has the same meaning).  The preceding `!` negates the sense of the test.

Answer (score 2):

`[[...]]` is a shell construct. `[[`, and `]]` being reserved words in the syntax of the shell, inside which the shell understands a form of micro-language called *conditional expression*.

That language is similar, but different in many subtle ways from the language made of the arguments passed to the `[` or `test` utilities.

The manual of your shell is the place to look for its documentation. That `[[...]]` construct is initially from the Korn shell and was copied by bash and zsh though with variations between them.

For `bash`, see the [*Conditional Constructs* node](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) of its configuration which you can get for the version installed on your system with:

```
info -n 'conditional constructs' bash
```

Which will describe the `[[...]]` operator, and you'll find in there a link to the [*Bash Conditional Expressions* node](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) which describes the micro-language understood within. Or you can get directly to that node with:

```
info -n 'Bash Conditional Expressions' bash
```

In there, you'll find:

> -S *file*
>
> True if *file* exists and is a socket.

So that:

```
echo "err: borg socket does not exist" >&2
```

is slightly misleading and should have been:

```
echo "err: borg socket does not exist or is not a socket" >&2
```

Though strictly speaking that should even be:

```
echo "err: borg socket does not exist or I can't determine whether it's a socket or not" >&2
```

Answer (score 1):

From `man test`  :

> -S FILE
> FILE exists and is a socket